# R split numeric vector at position

Tags: r, vector, split

I am wondering about the simple task of splitting a vector into two at a certain index:

```
splitAt <- function(x, pos){
  list(x[1:pos-1], x[pos:length(x)])
}

a <- c(1, 2, 2, 3)

> splitAt(a, 4)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 2

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

My question: There must be some existing function for this, but I can't find it? Is maybe `split` a possibility? My naive implementation also does not work if `pos=0` or `pos>length(a)`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

An improvement would be:

```
splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% pos)))
```

which can now take a vector of positions:

```
splitAt(a, c(2, 4))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
```

And it does behave *properly*  (subjective) if `pos <= 0` or `pos >= length(x)` in the sense that it returns the whole original vector in a single list item. If you'd like it to error out instead, use `stopifnot` at the top of the function.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for me! I am still surprised there is not a `splitAt` function implemented in base R...

Comment: This function is very slow with very large `x`, probably due to the `seq_along(x)` that creates a very long vector and then the `%in%` that has to match this very long vector.

Comment: @Calimo: no, if you profile it, you'll see that most of the time is spent inside the slowish `split`. You can certainly avoid it but you'll lose a lot in terms of readability and code compactness.

Answer (score 8):

I tried to use [flodel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357962/r-split-numeric-vector-at-position/16358095#16358095), but it was too slow in my case with a very large `x` (and the function has to be called repeatedly). So I created the following function that is much faster, but also very ugly and doesn't behave properly. In particular, it doesn't check anything and will return buggy results at least for `pos >= length(x)` or `pos <= 0` (you can add those checks yourself if you're unsure about your inputs and not too concerned about speed), and perhaps some other cases as well, so be careful.

```
splitAt2 <- function(x, pos) {
    out <- list()
    pos2 <- c(1, pos, length(x)+1)
    for (i in seq_along(pos2[-1])) {
        out[[i]] <- x[pos2[i]:(pos2[i+1]-1)]
    }
    return(out)
}
```

However, `splitAt2` runs about 20 times faster with an x of length 10<sup>6</sup>:

```
library(microbenchmark)
W <- rnorm(1e6)
splits <- cumsum(rep(1e5, 9))
tm <- microbenchmark(
                     splitAt(W, splits),
                     splitAt2(W, splits),
                     times=10)
tm
```

Comment: Thanks! Also with the simple example from above, `splitAt2` performs better.

Comment: +1 - a somewhat pretty rewrite could be: `function(x, pos) {pos <- c(1L, pos, length(x) + 1L); Map(function(x, i, j) x[i:j], list(x), head(pos, -1L), tail(pos, -1L) - 1L)}`. It also seems a bit faster as the number of splits increases, not sure why.

Comment: @user1981275 define "better". If better = faster I agree, but as a general purpose function robustness is key, in which case flodel's version is better.

Comment: @flodel indeed your rewrite is faster with a very large number of splits. Can't explain why either.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative that might be faster and/or more readable/elegant than [flodel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357962/r-split-numeric-vector-at-position/16358095#16358095):

```
splitAt <- function(x, pos) {
  unname(split(x, findInterval(x, pos)))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like flodel's solution in my practice.