# Divide vector with grouping vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have two vectors, which I would like to combine in one dataframe. One of the vectors `values` needs to be divided into two columns. The second vector `nc` informs about the number of values for each observation. If `nc` is 1, only one value is given in `values` (which goes into `val1`) and `999` is to be written in the second column (`val2`).

What is an r-ish way to divide vector `value` and populate the two columns of `df`? I suspect I miss something very obvious, but can't proceed at the moment...Many thanks!

```
set.seed(123)
nc <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
value <- sample(1:6, sum(nc), replace = TRUE)



# result by hand
df <- data.frame(nc = nc, 
               val1 = c(6, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 6, 5, 6, 5), 
               val2 = c(999, 5, 999, 6, 1, 999, 6, 4, 4, 999))
```

Comment: _"If nc is 1, only one value is given in values (which goes into val1) and 999 is to be written in the second column (val2)."_ <=> `df$val2 <- ifelse(df$nc == 1, 999, df$val2)` and `df$val1 <- ifelse(df$nc == 1, df$nc, df$val1)`?

Comment: No, I don't think that will work: if, e.g. nc[1] == 2 then you need to pick the first two values from `value`, if e.g. nc[1] == 1 then only the fist value from `value`. To find out, to which observation a value belongs to, I think, one needs to iterate through the entire list.

Comment: To clarify what exactly you need, please add the data frame with the  expected output to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358095/1256977):

```
set.seed(123)
nc <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
value <- sample(1:6, sum(nc), replace = TRUE)

splitUsing <- function(x, pos) {
    unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% cumsum(replace(pos, 1, pos[1] + 1)))))
}

combineValues <- function(vals, nums) {
    mydf <- data.frame(cbind(nums, do.call(rbind, splitUsing(vals, nums))))
    mydf$V3[mydf$nums == 1] <- 999
    return(mydf)
}

df <- combineValues(value, nc)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. I'm not sure it is the fastest way, but it should do the trick.

```
count <- 0
for (i in 1:length(nc)) {
    count <- count + nc[i]
    if(nc[i]==1) {
        df$val1[i] <- value[count]
        df$val2[i] <- 999
    } else {
        df$val1[i] <- value[count-1]
        df$val2[i] <- value[count]
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this code possibly does return the correct result, it certainly is not  the "r-ish way".