# subset in r using last value

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

I have a dataset like

```
 x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

and I want all the subsets with end value as true, for example:

```
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
FALSE FALSE TRUE
FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
FALSE TRUE
```

I have tried using loops and tried getting 5 value above `TRUE` but due to asymmetry I am not getting desired results. I have reproduced this example where original has some more discrepancies. Any solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your `for` loop

Comment: Also `trimws(strsplit(paste(x, collapse=" "), "(?<=TRUE)", perl=T)[[1]])`

Comment: can u explain using example?, thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using only two lines of code:

```
splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% pos)))

> splitAt(x, which(x)+1)
[[1]]
[1] "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" 

[[2]]
[1] "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" 

[[3]]
[1] "FALSE" "FALSE" "FALSE" "TRUE" 

[[4]]
[1] "FALSE" "TRUE"
```

**Data:**

```
x <- c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE",
       "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE",
       "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE",
       "FALSE", "TRUE")
```

I give credit to [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357962/r-split-numeric-vector-at-position) which thought of the very useful function `splitAt()` which I used above.

Comment: Variation on a theme, assuming `x <- as.logical(x)` - `split(x, sum(x) - rev(cumsum(rev(x))) )`

Comment: can i save it to data frame

Comment: What structure do you want?  The output you specified in your OP does not seem to lend itself well to a data frame.  A data frame can easily be converted to a list (it _is_ a list), but not vice-versa.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help, i have found a way to split the list and convert to dataframe using transpose function

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in a simple `lapply` in one line

```
lapply(diff(c(0, which(x))), function(x) c(rep(FALSE, (x-1)), TRUE))

#[[1]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[3]]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

#[[4]]
#[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

**Explanation**

- `which(x)` gives us the position of the `TRUE` values (`4, 7, 11, 13`)
- starting from 0, we want the difference between each TRUE (which is essentially the count of `FALSE`) - `diff(c(0, which(x)))` - `4 3 4 2`
- For each of these values we want a vector that is `length(x)`, with `x - 1` `FALSE` values, and `1` `TRUE` - `c(rep(FALSE, (x-1)), TRUE)`
- the `lapply` does this for each of the `4 3 4 2` values, and returns a list

**Benchmarking**

Comparing the solutions

```
library(microbenchmark)

splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% pos)))

microbenchmark(

  splitAt(x, which(x)+1),

  {r <- rle(x)$lengths
  lapply(r[seq(1,length(r), by=2)] , function(x) c(rep(FALSE, x), TRUE))},

  split(x, sum(x) - rev(cumsum(rev(x))) ),

  trimws(strsplit(paste(x, collapse=" "), "(?<=TRUE)", perl=T)[[1]]),

  lapply(diff(c(0, which(x))), function(x) c(rep(FALSE, (x-1)), TRUE))

)


  #    min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
  # 83.827  86.3910  91.76449  88.9155  92.8350 155.722   100
  # 94.373  97.6275 105.10872 101.1455 105.8545 307.927   100
  # 85.532  88.0660  93.59524  91.7935  95.3715 126.419   100
  #145.233 147.8755 152.65975 150.3250 156.5910 177.807   100
  # 26.451  29.6130  31.81785  31.0470  33.1895  43.267   100
```

**Data**

```
x <- c(F, F, F, T, F , F, T, F, F, F, T, F, T)
```