How do I calculate the mean for data segments for 1000 realizations of simulated data?
I am working on change point detection and want to estimate the number and location of change points (CP) for 1000 realizations of simulated data. I have already estimated the number of CPs and their locations and then I would calculate the mean at each data segment based on CP locations for each realization. I wrote a code that calculates the mean at each data segment based on CP locations that works only for 1 realization, but I am not able to extend it to 1000 realizations. So, I need your help and am kindly requesting your scholar support.
For example, to estimate change points (CP) for data generated using arma(2,6):
set.seed(111)
f <- rep(c(0, 5, 2, 8, 1, -2), c(100, 200, 200, 50, 200, 250))
x <- f + arima.sim(list(ar = c(.75, -.5), ma = c(.8, .7, .6, .5, .4, .3)), n = length(f), sd = 1)
wc=wcm.gsa(x)

using the detection method which has code by the authors
https://github.com/haeran-cho/wcm.gsa
CP=wc$cp
CP # CP= 95, 297, 500, 550, 750

to calculate the mean at each data segments i.e mean of x between [1:95], [96:297],[298:500], [501:550], [551:750], [751:1000]) based on CP location, I write the code:

for (i in 2:length(CP)) 
            {
       if(i==1)
       mn[i]=mean(x[1:CP[i]]) else
       mn[i]=mean(x[(CP[i-1]+1):CP[i]])
        }
      est.ft=print(c(mn[1:i], mean(x[(CP[length(CP)]+1):length(x)])))

I want to estimate CP and calculate the mean at each data segments based on CP location for 1000 realizations. I estimated CP for 1000 realizations using
y=as.data.frame(replicate(1000, f + arima.sim(list(ar = c(.75, -.5), ma = c(.8, .7, .6, .5, .4,  
           .3)), n = length(f), sd = 1)))
    wcm = function (x) wcm.gsa(x)$cp
    m=sapply(y[1:1000], wcm)


You are nearly there.  I adapted a function from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358095/12176280 on splitting a vector.
## This function splits a vector at changepoints and calculates the mean of each chunk.
splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% (pos+1)))) |> sapply(mean)

Check it works:
> splitAt(x,CP)
[1]  0.2429253  5.1971471  1.6105275  7.7804240  1.3270635 -2.0442541
> est.ft
[1]  0.2429253  5.1971471  1.6105275  7.7804240  1.3270635 -2.0442541

Then you can mapply this function with your list of vector y and your list of changepoints m (I only used 10 realisations for this test).
> mapply( splitAt , x=y, pos=m)

$V1
[1]  0.4128471  5.5288876  2.7397518  8.5439779  0.7192723  3.3075475 -2.2773475

$V2
[1] -0.3943777  3.3181151  6.9971671  1.1576218 -1.8598642

$V3
[1] -0.9368701  4.2092452  0.9656501  7.2576583  0.9931713 -2.2473779

$V4
[1] -0.2403794  5.1575427  1.5175894  8.2009883  2.7080846  0.9270326 -2.1582418

$V5
[1] -0.3436777  4.9006335  2.9385906  0.9303320 -2.7066879

$V6
[1] -0.9856804  4.3627405  1.4778232  6.8431225  1.1335163 -1.7233991

$V7
[1]  0.2859023  4.9725381  1.9741004  6.1717678  1.7284418 -2.3646056

$V8
[1] -0.6060031  4.8036211  1.9822621  8.6880420  0.5106320 -2.2751981

$V9
[1] -0.4341405  4.4911962  1.6182828  7.7579370  0.4405483 -2.4892161

$V10
[1]  0.4838477  4.8951024  2.0386160  7.9571610  1.8665128 -1.7820840


Thanks so much, the code works perfectly. But I want to replicate each mean for CP[i]-CP[i-1] times for i=1, ..., length(CP)+1 where length(CP)+1= length(x). So, would you please edit the code accordingly. Thanks

@Tare Replace splitAt with:
splitAt <- function(x, pos) ave(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% (pos+1)), FUN=mean)

Thank you so much for your scholar support, the code works without any error.

I am very grateful to @stackoverflow.com for providing this platform to assist academicians challenged with some coding problems.

would you please check the question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78442222/calculate-covering-metric-for-evaluating-performance-of-change-point-detection-m?
