How to calculate covering metric to evaluate performance of change point detection methods
Covering metric (CM) evaluates how the data segment produced by detected   change point align with ground-truth segment formed by true change point.
Theory to implement CM

I want to calculate CM for the data generated with 10 realizations and it will be obtained by taking the average of CM of each realization.
I tried to write a code that works for one realization. I also extended it for 10 realizations, but it counters a problem on determining the length segments produced by the estimated and true change points.
Code for CM for 'DeCAFS` change point detection method for one realization
library(DeCAFS)
set.seed(2001)
x=rep(c(0,2,-2,2,-2), c(200,200,200,200, 200))+rnorm(1000) # data with change points (CP)
TCP=c(200,400,600,800)   # True CP locations
splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% (pos+1)))) 
split_by_TCP=splitAt(x, TCP) # partition the data into segments based on TPC

estCP=DeCAFS(x,warningMessage = FALSE)$changepoints  #estimate CPs using DeCAFS method
split_by_estCP=splitAt(x, estCP)  # partition the data into segments based on estimated CPs

# determine the intersection between segments produced from true CPs and estimated CPs
intersec=(Map(\(split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP) intersect(split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP), split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP))

#computes the cardinality of the intersection
cardinality_intersection=sapply(intersec,length)

# determine the union between segments produced from true CPs and estimated CPs
unionn=(Map(\(split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP) union(split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP), split_by_TCP, split_by_estCP))

# computes the cardinality of the union
cardinality_union=sapply(unionn, length)

#Calculate CM
CM=(1/length(x))*sum(sapply(split_by_TCP, length)*(max((cardinality_intersection)/(cardinality_intersection))))

print(CM)

For 10 realizations, I used the following code for DeCAFS method, but failed
set.seed(1111)
y=as.data.frame(replicate(10,rep(c(0,2,-2,2,-2), c(200,200,200,200, 200))+rnorm(1000)))
decafs = function (x) DeCAFS(x, warningMessage = FALSE)$changepoints
mw=sapply(y, decafs) #stores estimated CPs
C=rep(c(200,400,600,800),10) # replicate True CPs for 10 realisations 
ps=head(seq(4, 40, by=4),-1)  # positions to split True CPs
splitAt <- function(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% (pos+1)))) 
s=splitAt(C, ps)  # split True CPs for 10 realisations
seg_TCP=mapply(splitAt,x=y, pos=s) #stores segments from true CPs for 10 realisations
seg_estCPs=mapply(splitAt,x=y,pos=mw) # stores segments from estimated CPs for 10 realisations


@Friede Suppose I've time series data {yt}, t=1,…,100 with 2 true change points (CP) at tau1=20 & tau2=40. Then I will have 3 data segments (S1,S2, &S3) where S1={y1,..,y20}, S2={ y21,...,y40} & S3= {y41,..y100}. Let the estimated CP be tau’1=18 & tau’2=42 that yields segments S’1={ y1,…,y18} , S’2= {y19,..,y42} & S’3={ y43,..., y100}. Next, I’ll take max(length(S1nS’1)/length(S1uS’1), length(S2nS’2)/length(S2uS’2), length(S3nS’3)/length(S3uS’3)). Then multiply the maximum with the corresponding length(S1), length(S2) & length(S3) & sum them. Finally, covering metric will be sum divide by 100.

@Friede, I will calculate covering metric for each of 10 realizations following the above procedure and take the average of 10 realizations.

Updated.
Set-up
Your data generating processes.
set.seed(0508)
n = rep(200L, 5L)
tcp = cumsum(n)[-length(n)]
x = rep(c(0L, 2L, -2L, 2L, -2L), n) + rnorm(1e3) 
y = as.data.frame(replicate(10L, rep(c(0L, 2L, -2L, 2L, -2L), n) + rnorm(1e3))) 

Theory to implement

Note. Not too sure how the max works.
Implementation of cm()
cm = \(x, tcp) { # x := data series, # tcp := true change points 
  stopifnot(is.atomic(x), is.vector(tcp))  
  ecp = DeCAFS::DeCAFS(x, warningMessage = FALSE)$changepoints
  if(length(ecp) != length(tcp)) {
    # you might consider to add a warning 
    NA # you might want to change to a more informative value/string
  } else {
    splitAt = \(x, pos) unname(split(x, cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% pos)))
    # from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16358095/20002111
    tecp = lapply(list("tcp" = tcp, "ecp" = ecp), \(i) splitAt(x, i))
    cA = lengths(tecp[["tcp"]])
    M = mapply(\(x, y) length(intersect(x, y)) / length(union(x, y)), tecp[["tcp"]], tecp[["ecp"]])
    sum(M * cA) / length(x)
  }
}

First try
gives
> cm(x, tcp)
[1] 1

> vapply(y, \(j) cm(j, tcp), numeric(1L))
       V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6 
       NA        NA        NA 0.9960100 0.9920495        NA 
       V7        V8        V9       V10 
0.9980050 0.9980050 1.0000000 1.0000000 

Note
It seems like DeCAFS::DeCAFS() and its underlying algorithm does not offer an option to set the number of estimated change points a priori. For the moment, data series where the number of estimated change points (necp) deviates from the number of true change points are excluded, an NA is reported. (If you know a way how to set necp via an argument of DeCAFS::DeCAFS() adapt accordingly, or develop a legitime procedure how to proceed). Notice that exclusion introduces a systematic bias.

I appreciate your work. I hope you received my email message recently and will come up with a final version of the code that includes the number of estimated change points which deviates from the* number of true change points*. I think the code will work for other detection methods, right?

I tried to check the output of your updated code for necp that deviates from the number of true change points generated with warning message by computing manually based on ecp without if -else condition. It seems correct, but I think on splitAt, pos=pos+1.

(1) Yes. A possibility will be to wrap ecp = DeCAFS::DeCAFS(x ,... in if(missing(ecp)) { } (default) and make ecp an argument of cm(). Then you can either pass a vector of ecp to cm() or use the default. (2) It's not a question of the code, but of your design. Develope a legitimate and solid concept. Code implementation is downstream process. As I mentioned, it seems like DeCAFS::DeCAFS() does not offer an option (argument) to set the number of estimated change points (necp) a priori. This is probably due to a reason. If you do not understand the methode, do not use it!

How? Is q \neq \hat{q} (LaTeX) valid?
